# Read gpx track points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gpx

I want to read GPX track points with their time stamps into QGIS. I try GPS Tools, GPX Conversions, Waypoints from a track.

This fails on my PC at office (QGIS code revision d94c044). Sometimes QGIS stalls with high CPU usage, but most times I get an error "The layer C:/Daten/CurrT.gpx?type=waypoint is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map".

It works on my Laptop at home (QGIS code revision ebebdf3), but the created features don't contain timestamps. Fields are name, elevation, comment, description, source, url, url name.

How should I proceed?

BTW both versions of QGIS insist "You are running the current version of QGIS" and don't offer updates. Is it reasonable to re-install the (apparently) same version of QGIS from time to time?

Comment: Check in http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input +advanced select Duplicate as waypoints:with timestamps  output as plain text and load in QGIS>Layer >Add Delimited Text Layer

Comment: Would opening the GPX file as an input vector solve the problem?

Comment: Mapperz: Thanks for the pointer. I want to process the data local, so probably will end writing a python script for this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ryan Garnett gave the simple solution as comment: Layer, Add Vector Layer, MyGPX.gpx, then select "track_points" works perfect.

Comment: indeed -- for those with newer Garmin GPSs which allow one to access the internal storage as a USB drive this is a much better way of loading the data.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar a while back.

Have a look at the GPX file (in a plain text editor) to make sure wpt all have `<time></time>` tags. It can happen that some don't. My case was GPX originating from a small Garmin where a single "saved track" amidst the active log resulted in the problem.

Removing the records which have no time (such as in the first 6 lines below) did the trick for me. Perhaps it is just that. Good luck!
    ...

```
<wpt lat="-33.800293012" lon="151.283615911">
  <ele>16.479736</ele>
  <name>WPT2995</name>                 # ooops no time!
  <cmt>WPT2995</cmt>
  <desc>WPT2995</desc>
</wpt>
<wpt lat="49.256153500" lon="-78.116246384">
  <ele>396.200562</ele>
  <time>2013-05-11T15:33:39Z</time>    # good !
  <name>WPT2996</name>
  <cmt>WPT2996</cmt>
  <desc>WPT2996</desc>
</wpt>
...
```

Comment: Also, check that the timezone shown is Z. From the GPX schema: "Creation/modification timestamp for element. Date and time in are in Univeral Coordinated Time (UTC), not local time! Conforms to ISO 8601 specification for date/time representation."

Comment: I double checked one GPX result, that is _after_ using GPX Conversions. All wpt elements contain a time element in the range "2013-11-26T06:06:52Z" - "2013-11-26T07:37:30Z". Only the subsequent import as QGIS layer seems to fail.