# How can I edit gpx tracks, property timestamp and waypoints?

Tags: gpx, map-editor, timestamp

I want to reconstruct the historical movements of a military regiment. I am looking for a publisher, in the end I wish a gpx file. A priori there is full, yet I find none that corresponds: I need to display a map to determine where to put my points (with dates and hour-> timestamp) and sometimes some waypoints (for battle etc. ...).

Gpx files seems very appropriate, but what editor use ? I tried garmin basecamp, but I can't edit timestamp. I looked josm, but I do not feel that I can edit the tracks without losing the timestamp when I export ... well, I do not find (or I search very badly: /) an editor allows to create manually (visually) plots, edit timestamp and waypoints.

Can anyone guide me?

I want a editor to display a map on the screen and click at specific positions to create a point and give this point a timestamp and export to GPX file. In the end, I use the gpx file with osm and D3, but it's not my question. I not use a gps device, I don't want to import gpx file in a editor because I want to create track and waypoints myself from archive military documents.

I just want to transcript this kind of military log (dates, places and events) to a map. It's very long to do, so I prefer to have a GUI to input each event at once.

[Exemple](http://www.memoiredeshommes.sga.defense.gouv.fr/fr/ark:/40699/e0052753306c9d09/527533070eb9d) of a log (sorry it's in french).

Comment: It is not clear in what format you have your data. Or is it that you want to create data (points with timestamps)?

Comment: GPX is just an XML (http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd) You could edit it with an XML viewer or Text viewer... one key at a time. Do you have any coding ability? C# has a few objects that would make this task easy.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to display a map on the screen and click at specific positions to create a point and give this point a timestamp and eventually export to GPX. Confirm that this is your need and then specify in which format is this map in.

Comment: yes, that's exactly it! Sorry if I'm not very clear. In the end I want to export a GPX file  (with track and waypoint. I will use with OSM and d3.js, but that's not my question;)).

Comment: QGIS can do everything that you are asking and its free

Comment: Thank you all. This need sounded to me simple: on one hand I have a military log consists of dates and events, on the other side, I wanted to place on map each event and enter the date. Gps files seemed ideals to represent a "spatio temporal" information . This inventory work is very long, so I wanted a GUI to do everything at once, without having to edit the file (or code). To give you an idea, added in question, a link to a military log : every day over 4 years of war is detailed. And this for each regiment. I will try Qgis and close my question if that answers my need ! Thanks again :)!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and use the [GPS plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html). The plugin allow you to import the gpx file, edit and save the changes. You can also add imagery into the background by using the [Open Layers plugin](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/openlayers).

To import and edit:

- Open QGIS
- Go Vector>GPS>GPS Tools
  [image]
- When the GPS Tools window opens, browse to the gpx file you want to add and hit ok.
  [image]
- When the GPX is added to the layers window, right click on the the layer you want to edit and select "Open Attribute Table"
- With the Attribute Table open, click the pencil icon to start editing
  [image]
  [image]
- When editing, change the required items. In this example, I just changed the names.
  [image]
- When finished editing, hit the save button and then the pencil button to stop editing.
  [image]
- The changes should now be reflected in the original gpx file
  [image]

After compiling this answer, I realised that this method won't allow you to see the time/date stamp. There is answer located [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/78856/18320) that explains how to view the time/date stamp in QGIS. However, this method won't allow you to edit the file unless you save it as something else. In my test I saved the gpx file as a shapefile (right mouse click on gpx and save as ESRI Shapefile), changed the time/date in the attribute file and then re-saved it as a gpx.

Comment: Thank you for your very detail answer ! Indeed, this is not exactly what i need. I have completed my question (see the edit). I will read the link earlier and will comment :). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I think GPSbabel can do that. I remember that we can specify à time offset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, if i'am not wrong, gpsbabel doesn't have a gui for place points. So It's hard to me to first place points on a soft (like basecamp) and then, edit timestamp with another software like gpsbabel. Indeed, research on movements army is about 4 years with thousands places so it's not very easy when points are place while reading archive documents...not sure if my comment is clear ;). But in synthese, I like to place points and tag the date at the same moment.