# Error Code -2147483647 when combining vector layers

Tags: qgis, layers, merge, error

I am trying to combine multiple vector layers in QGIS using the "merge vector layers" function from the dropdown lists

```
(vector -> Data Management Tools -> Merge Vector Layers)
```

All data are point data but when I run the process it returns `"-2147483647 See log for more details"` and when I open the log message panel it shows `"key error -214783647"`.

Can someone please explain what this error is and how I can remedy it?

**Edit** 
I'm using QGIS 2.18
The point data I'm using is waypoint data from 2 surveys which were uploaded to Google Earth and saved as a .kml file. I uploaded it to QGIS where each set of points shows as separate layers and would like to combine them into a single layer then save as a shapefile.
link to data:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=109K5lobpPGVHNVmG3R43nLUt1HTXHinH

I hope this clarifies some. I'm no GIS wiz.

Comment: hi, welcome to gis stackExchange. Can you tell us what is your QGIS Version and can you describe your point dataset please ? can you reproduce it with another dataset ?

Comment: edited the question above

Comment: What's in the log? Are you trying to combine two KML files into a single KML file? Can you try to merge as Esri Shapefile and see if that works any better.

Comment: The points are in same layer.

Comment: @neogeomat the points are in a single file but when you upload the KML file to QGIS they file separates the points into 2 different layers (for the 2 survey efforts).

Comment: Even in Qgis they are in one layer, although qgis displays 2 layers both layers have same data.

Comment: @Michael Stimson I am trying to take the 2 layers from the KML file and combine them into 1 layer so I can save it as a single shapefile. I need to sent this data to a colleague in shapefile format and having a single shapefile is easier to use than multiple ones (there are more files I need to do this with).  Some of the data sets work but others don't. I'm not sure what you mean by merging as ESRI Shapefile as opposed to merge layers.

Comment: @neogeomat when I look at the 2 layers and attributes tables, one has 3 points and the other has 12 points. So, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Esri Shapefile is a format http://www.gdal.org/drv_shapefile.html .. unfortunately there seems to be a tendency to call any geographic data a shapefile but only an Esri shapefile truly is a shapefile. Geographic storage formats have different specific properties so it's important to refer to your output/input data formats as what they really are.

Comment: @mmontgomery but on loading, there are only 3 points in both layers.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I understand that part. I don't understand how to merge as esri shapefile if what you are suggesting is different than merge the layers and save the output as a shapefile.

Comment: Try converting both layers to an Esri shapefile with *save as* then merge both shapefiles.

Comment: @MichaelStimson This is actually why I'm trying this in QGIS. I normally do this in DNR Garmin (yes, it's old school) but it's not working properly and freezing. I've tried GPS Babel but it doesn't output/convert TO shapefile only FROM shapefile. Do you have a suggestion for a free program that will do this (I don't have Arc GIS)?

Comment: @neogeomat that's strange, I just tested the link and file several times and see one layer with 3 points and the other with 12 points. Not sure what's going on from your end. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I bumped into this post a while back that might help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78812/read-gpx-track-points-in-qgis is your GPS data in GPX format? If it's KML (not KMZ) you can add it to the QGIS canvas then right click on each layer in turn and select 'save as', choose the driver Esri Shapefile and save (new shapefile layer should be added to canvas) then merge (https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/Merge might help) **unless** your layers are not the same geometry type, you can't merge points and polygons or lines in the same shapefile.

Comment: Ok. I see what you're  saying now. Just adding the step or doing it backwards from what I'm currently doing. I'll try that and see how it goes. Thanks!